# Tomcat war deployment error with successful maven install caused by org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, maven, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a war file in tomcat and i get the below error when deploying. I used maven to install and did not see any errors. When i deploy tomcat i see the following error in logs. I dont have application.xml setup.

Any help appreciated!!!

```
 02-Jun-2019 11:31:02.539 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/deploywar]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/MBeanServerNotification
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.lambda$registerMetricsEventually$bca24a20$1(TomcatMetrics.java:225)

    ... 20 more

02-Jun-2019 11:31:02.539 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\deploywar.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/deploywar]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

02-Jun-2019 11:31:22.539 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/deploywar]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1370)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/MBeanServerNotification
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.tomcat.TomcatMetrics.lambda$registerMetricsEventually$bca24a20$1(TomcatMetrics.java:225)
    at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more

02-Jun-2019 11:31:22.539 SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\deploywar.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/deploywar]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)


02-Jun-2019 11:31:22.539 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\deploywar.war] has finished in [0] ms
```

Below is my  pom.xml snippet.There are testing done during maven install too but those passed no errors.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
         <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Please run: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-dao` and append it's output to the question. Did you rebuild the project using `mvn clean package` after removing `<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>` from the dependencies ?

Comment: I ran the mvn dependency and it downloaded a bunch of stuff then shows success message. I did a mvn clean package using the updated pom from above and got a new set of errors... Is the POM looking ok or i should remove something else?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the Dependency issue. Here are few steps using it you can resolve them.

**1) Add below plugin into your pom build tag.**

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <dependencyConvergence />
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

then run  *mvn enforcer:enforce*

This will give you all the list of conflict dependency with their group Id and artifact id and you just need to exclude from the relative dependency.

This is very helpful method.

**2) Second way.**

Run mvn dependency:tree command from pom directory.

This will list you all the dependency and their sub dependency in a tree structure and you will have to look after the tree list and find duplicate one and then exclude them from relative dependency.

I would suggest you to try with first step its very easy and clear to resolve.

Hope this will help you.